# css not applying in wordpress divi theme button module settings, advanced tab

Tags: html, css, wordpress

CSS code not applying in Divi Theme, button module settings, advanced tab.

I'm trying to add css code to the advanced tab of a button module on my homepage. www.LumiWave.com, bottom of page. The button is labeled "explore products"

Currently Running
WordPress 4.7.6
Divi 3.0.72 by Elegant Themes

Here is what I'm doing:
From the button module, I'm clicking settings.
From there I click the Advanced tab.
At the top, in the "CSS Class:" field I input "greenbutton" as the class name. 
Then I scroll down to the "Main Element:" section and paste in the following:

```
.greenbutton:link {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 253.188px;
  height: 51px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font: normal normal bold 14px/25.5px “Roboto”, sans-serif;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  background: #78b657;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1);
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1);
}

.greenbutton:hover {
  border: 1px solid #78b657;
  color: #78b657;
  background: rgba(124, 218, 36, 0.2);
}
```

It doesn't apply the style sheet settings, instead in continues to grab the settings from the main button style settings area.

From wordpress admin, if I customize the Divi theme by going to appearance -> customize -> buttons -> button style or button hover style, that is where it is still grabbing its settings from.

I know that I can configure this from design tab if I want to and I may end up having to do that if I can't get this to work, but the advanced CSS tab is supposed to work and I wanted to play around with a few advanced settings that I can't get from the design tab alone.

The settings all work as expected on css tool sites, I'm thinking it has something to do with the way I'm entering or defining the class name, but from all the references I could find it looks correct.

Comment: put this code in in your theme option > custom css section.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, this post was specifically about how to get the Advanced tab in the Divi Module working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but for anyone having troubles with this issue:
The Modules custom css option takes the code you write and inserts it into a selector for that module.
Instead of writing code like this:

```
.element-class{
  color:'red';
  background-color: 'blue';
}
```

Just type it like this:

```
color:'red';
background-color: 'blue';
```

If you want to use your selectors you'd need to either use the custom css option for the page or to use an external stylesheet.